# "The system cannot find the path specified" : Anaconda Geopandas Installation Issue

Tags: python, pandas, gis, gdal, geopandas

I have installed geopandas through "conda install geopandas" command. It installed successfully but this end with this message "The system cannot find the path specified". As you can see in the image below: [image] If someone can assist me to resolve this and can tell me that what is the reason behind it?

Comment: If it really did install successfully, why do you care about the error message?

Comment: I posted this, because Should I care about the driver path of GDAL? which has not been set yet? Can this create problem in future operations like reverse geocoding ?

Comment: That screenshot does not contain enough details to even begin to answer that.

Comment: Although my real point was, even though you _said_ it installed successfully, it sounds like you're not sure that it actually did.

Comment: Installed successfully means that when i import the library it succefully imported in python script. but my worry is that why GDAL Driver path was not set, would it be problematic in future operation like reverse geocoding?

Comment: Again, I have no idea how to answer that question.  The screenshot does not say  anything beyond a simple error message.

Comment: ok , i concluded that this particular error has nothing to do with reverse geocoding but for any other geo operation might be this effect. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: 2 things would be interesting: 1. Which OS are you using (probably Windows I guess)? 2. What status does the error message refer to (GDAL_DRIVER_PATH? Or anything during the installation)?

Comment: yes i am using windows. Yes , set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH? but this message pop up after the installation. I have searched alot but no answer of this i found in communities.